# How can I use semaphore to describe precedence graph?

Tags: semaphore

[image]

How can I Use semaphores to describe the synchronization of the eight processes in the general
precedence graph above?

Comment: okay the question is very specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   p1        p2        p3        p4        p5        p6        p7        p8
=============================================================================
    .         .         .         .         .        .         .          .
  work        .         .         .         .        .         .          .
    |         .         .         .         .        .         .          .
V(s1, 3)    P(s1)       .         .       P(s1)      .        P(s1)       .
    x         |         .         .         |        .          |         .
            work        .         .         |        .          |         .
              |         .         .         |        .          |         .
          V(s2, 2)    P(s2)     P(s2)      work      .          |         .
              x         |         |         |        .          |         .
                        |       work        |        .         work       .
                        |         |         |        .          |         .
                      work    V(s3, 1)   V(s3, 1)   P(s3)       |         .
                        |         x         x       P(s3)       |         .
                        |                             |         |         .
                        |                           work        |         .
                        |                             |         |         .
                    V(s4, 1)                      V(s4, 1)   V(s4, 1)    P(s4)
                        x                             x         x        P(s4)
                                                                         P(s4)
                                                                           |
                                                                         work
                                                                           |
                                                                           x
```

Comment: small-p p-*n* is the process. capital-p P() is P-Operation or Wait operation. capital-v V() is the Signal operation. small-s s-*n* are the semaphores. V(s-*n*, m) means signal semaphore s-*n* m times. a semaphore signaled m times can allow m processes to pass